# 502 Bad Gateway - jQuery / AJAX Form

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I'm using the Ajax Form (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to submit a form I've created.

Locally, this works perfectly... But when I put it on the server, it's throwing this error in the console...

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)          https://website.co.uk/shop/tents-by-brand/easy-camp

If I press the button a second time, I get this error

> POST https://website.co.uk/shop/tents-by-brand/easy-camp 502 (Bad Gateway) jquery.min.js:4
>   send 
>   f.extend.ajax 
>   $.fn.ajaxSubmit
>   doAjaxSubmit
>   f.event.dispatch
>   h.handle.i

Is it possibly something to do with the SSL / HTTPS?

My code looks like this:

```
        function updateCart(data, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            if (data.success) {
                $("input[name=XID]").val(data.XID);
                $('.cart-total').html(data.cart_total);
                $("#notification-content").text('The item has been added to your basket');
                $("#notification-alt").delay(2000).fadeOut(
                    500,
                    function(){
                        $("#notification-content").text('Please wait... Adding item to basket.');
                    }

                );
            }
            return true; 
        }

    // Ajax Form Options

        var ajaxFormOptions = {
            success: updateCart,
            dataType: 'json'
        }

    // Form Actions

        $(".cart-submit-button").click(function(event){

            $("#notification-alt").fadeIn(500)

            var formId = $(this).parent('form').attr('id');
            var formIdHash = '#' + formId;

            $(formIdHash).ajaxForm(ajaxFormOptions);

            console.log('Clicked = ' + formId);

        });
```

Comment: Any clues in your browsers console window?

Comment: You have not trusted SSL certificate, I think it may be trouble source

Comment: If you are getting a 502 response I'd be inclined to think it is more to do with your server configuration than anything you have done client side.

Comment: @DaveHogan The console output is in the question :)

Comment: @Eugene The certificate is valid and green, all assets are loading correctly through HTTPS also

Comment: @stephenmuss Such as what? Is there anything I can tweak on the server to make AJAX posts work correctly? Like I said, it works locally on MAMP, just not online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I ended up turning `nginx` off on my Plesk server to fix the issue.

To turn off `nginx` on a Plesk server:

> Home > Tools Settings > Service Management > Stop Reverse Proxy (nginx)

Comment: Turning off Nginx is kind of extreme, though, since you lose all the benefits of it (using it as a reverse proxy gets you better speed and a reduction in bandwidth usage). If it's an Nginx config issue, you should be able to *configure* Nginx properly to not throw the errors!